# Thread Java, code slowdowns PC, making an easy autoclick

Tags: java

I started studying Java a while ago. I want to create an autoclick that starts clicking when I press a key, but when I do it the PC slowdowns and I can't do anything.

```
public class Main{


    public static void main(String... args){
        Robot robot = null;
        try {
            robot = new Robot();
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        RobotRunnable run = new RobotRunnable(robot);

        Thread t = new Thread(run);

        t.start();

        JFrame main = new JFrame();
        main.setSize(300, 300);
        main.setVisible(true);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        label.setText("false");
        panel.add(label);



        panel.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_G){
                    run.switchState();
                    label.setText(""+run.getState());

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

            }
        });

        main.add(panel);

        panel.setFocusable(true);
        panel.requestFocusInWindow();
        main.setVisible(true);



    }
}
```

RobotRunnable class:

```
public class RobotRunnable implements Runnable{

    Robot robot;

    public RobotRunnable(Robot robot){
        this.robot = robot;
    }

    private boolean enabled = false;
    @Override
    public void run() {

        while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){

            while(enabled){
                robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
                robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    public void switchState(){
        enabled = !enabled;
    }
    public boolean getState(){
        return enabled;
    }
}
```

It should click every 0.1 seconds but when I press G the computer slowdowns and I can't do anything.
Can you please tell me what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Your `Thread.sleep` should be inside the `while`:

```
            while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && enabled){
                robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                     Thread.currentThread.interrupt();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Mhhhh i need to make the thread execute even if  its not enabled
i changed the 2nd while to "if"

Comment: Or is it a bad practice to have a a thread's lifetime equals to the program's lifetime